# JPEG header construction

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, header, format, jpeg

I'm trying to write a JPEG file.

After I acquire the raw image and processing it by DCT, quantization and huffman coding, I would like to save it in the correct format. I couldn't find any libraries that help me to write proper header file, insert the two tables that I used (huffman and quantization), so I started writing everything by myself.

I started with the SOI marker, frame header and so on, but when I try to open the JPEG image with a viewer, it shows nothing, even in the properties. There's no information shown (e.g. the image dimension), even if I insert this info like written in the official documentation.

How can I write a proper JPEG header?

P.S
I use C++ and Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Share a sample file that you've created so far and I can tell you what part is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer - it's complicated.

I would start with [libjpeg](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libjpeg/) and use it to just give you the approriate header. You can also use it as a reference for what the internal header structs look like

Comment: libjpeg it's useless, it do not show how the header is write, there is a function that compress and save the image, but nothing like "write header" function or similar...

Comment: @user1466609, libjpeg is distributed as source. Look in the source and find the spot where it writes the header.

Comment: yes, i'm searching, but i cannot still find where i could insert my own huffman table or quantization table... some function allowd to write some marker, but they are a little bit twisted...